# StructureMap thinks it has to inject to constructor and throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

I'm using StructureMap and ASP.Net Identity in my application. When I have this line in my `Application_Start`

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
```

and this is `StructureMapControllerFactory`:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null && requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Page not found: {0}",
                requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;
    }
}
```

`return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType) as Controller;` throws a `StructureMapConfigurationException` exception saying:

```
No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IUserStore<Person>'
```

but if I remove `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());` line everything goes fine so it's StructureMap's problem not my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the exception is clear. It's probably about the AccountController from the Identity template, which comes with 2 constructors.

StructureMap will use the [most greediest constructor](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/constructor-selection/) by default. The template comes with 2 constructors, one default constructor and one constructor with an `ApplicationUserManager` object.

Without StructureMap the default constructor is called and the ApplicationUserManager will be resolved using the [service locator anti pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

StructureMap now must create the `ApplicationUserManager` and because this is a concrete type it will try. If it was an abstract it will throw the exception right there. The `ApplicationUserManager` however has a single constructor which needs an `IUserStore<Person>`. Because this is an abstract and the container has no registration of this type, StructureMap is unable to create the type for you.

To solve this you should remove the default constructor and Register the ApplicationUserManager and depending services which is at least some component which, implements IUserStore.

**Edit:**
While the solution you mentioned in the comments may work, this is not the preferable solution because of:

1. [Having multiple constructors is an anti-pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97)
2. You are now using the service locator anti pattern for resolving the `ApplicationUserManager` from the `HttpContext`

The templates that come with VS2013 need some work to use with dependency injection. This will cost some time. The good news is, it is possible and doable and will greatly improve your knowledge of `Owin`, `Asp.Net Identity`, Dependency Injection and [SOLID design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

There are several blogs on how to start refactoring the templates to work with dependency injection. You could read about that [here](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/discussions/564822) and [here](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/)

Comment: Thanks for the reason. but StructureMap supports multiple constructors. I've added this to my config and that worked :) `x.ForConcreteType<AccountController>().Configure.SelectConstructor(() => new AccountController());` so please update your answer so I check it as accepted.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: See my edit about the constructor. Also edited my answer as a reaction on your solution